# Save each sheet in a workbook to separate CSV files

Tags: excel, vba, csv

How do I save each sheet in an Excel workbook to separate `CSV` files with a macro?

I have an excel with multiple sheets and I was looking for a macro that will save each sheet to a separate `CSV (comma separated file)`. Excel will not allow you to save all sheets to different `CSV` files.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Here is one that will give you a visual file chooser to pick the folder you want to save the files to and also lets you choose the CSV delimiter (I use pipes '|' because my fields contain commas and I don't want to deal with quotes):

```
' ---------------------- Directory Choosing Helper Functions -----------------------
' Excel and VBA do not provide any convenient directory chooser or file chooser
' dialogs, but these functions will provide a reference to a system DLL
' with the necessary capabilities
Private Type BROWSEINFO    ' used by the function GetFolderName
    hOwner As Long
    pidlRoot As Long
    pszDisplayName As String
    lpszTitle As String
    ulFlags As Long
    lpfn As Long
    lParam As Long
    iImage As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" _
                                             Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" (ByVal pidl As Long, ByVal pszPath As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32.dll" _
                                           Alias "SHBrowseForFolderA" (lpBrowseInfo As BROWSEINFO) As Long

Function GetFolderName(Msg As String) As String
    ' returns the name of the folder selected by the user
    Dim bInfo As BROWSEINFO, path As String, r As Long
    Dim X As Long, pos As Integer
    bInfo.pidlRoot = 0&    ' Root folder = Desktop
    If IsMissing(Msg) Then
        bInfo.lpszTitle = "Select a folder."
        ' the dialog title
    Else
        bInfo.lpszTitle = Msg    ' the dialog title
    End If
    bInfo.ulFlags = &H1    ' Type of directory to return
    X = SHBrowseForFolder(bInfo)    ' display the dialog
    ' Parse the result
    path = Space$(512)
    r = SHGetPathFromIDList(ByVal X, ByVal path)
    If r Then
        pos = InStr(path, Chr$(0))
        GetFolderName = Left(path, pos - 1)
    Else
        GetFolderName = ""
    End If
End Function
'---------------------- END Directory Chooser Helper Functions ----------------------

Public Sub DoTheExport()
    Dim FName As Variant
    Dim Sep As String
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim nFileNum As Integer
    Dim csvPath As String


    Sep = InputBox("Enter a single delimiter character (e.g., comma or semi-colon)", _
                   "Export To Text File")
    'csvPath = InputBox("Enter the full path to export CSV files to: ")

    csvPath = GetFolderName("Choose the folder to export CSV files to:")
    If csvPath = "" Then
        MsgBox ("You didn't choose an export directory. Nothing will be exported.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each wsSheet In Worksheets
        wsSheet.Activate
        nFileNum = FreeFile
        Open csvPath & "\" & _
             wsSheet.Name & ".csv" For Output As #nFileNum
        ExportToTextFile CStr(nFileNum), Sep, False
        Close nFileNum
    Next wsSheet

End Sub



Public Sub ExportToTextFile(nFileNum As Integer, _
                            Sep As String, SelectionOnly As Boolean)

    Dim WholeLine As String
    Dim RowNdx As Long
    Dim ColNdx As Integer
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim EndRow As Long
    Dim StartCol As Integer
    Dim EndCol As Integer
    Dim CellValue As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo EndMacro:

    If SelectionOnly = True Then
        With Selection
            StartRow = .Cells(1).Row
            StartCol = .Cells(1).Column
            EndRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
            EndCol = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column
        End With
    Else
        With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            StartRow = .Cells(1).Row
            StartCol = .Cells(1).Column
            EndRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
            EndCol = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column
        End With
    End If

    For RowNdx = StartRow To EndRow
        WholeLine = ""
        For ColNdx = StartCol To EndCol
            If Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value = "" Then
                CellValue = ""
            Else
                CellValue = Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value
            End If
            WholeLine = WholeLine & CellValue & Sep
        Next ColNdx
        WholeLine = Left(WholeLine, Len(WholeLine) - Len(Sep))
        Print #nFileNum, WholeLine
    Next RowNdx

EndMacro:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: As the question didn't call for a non standard delimiter I'm unclear why you wrote a cell by cell routine. If you are going down this route work with variant arrays not ranges, recalc the `UsedRange` before referring to it (remove potential excess space), concatenate the longs strings with combined short strings `WholeLine = WholeLine & (CellValue & Sep)`, use string functions not variants (`Left$` not `Left`) etc

Answer (score 93):

@AlexDuggleby: you don't need to copy the worksheets, you can save them directly. e.g.:

```
Public Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SaveToDirectory As String

    SaveToDirectory = "C:\"

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        WS.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & WS.Name, xlCSV
    Next

End Sub
```

Only potential problem is that that leaves your workbook saved as the last csv file. If you need to keep the original workbook you will need to SaveAs it.

Comment: +1 To use in Excel, one can: Alt+F11, Insert > Module, Paste code, Click the play button.

Comment: Another problem, doesn't work if saved in your personal workbook. Otherwise Excellent!

Comment: @bishop how to run this code? I pasted it in the VBA editor in Excel 2016 on MAC but not able to run. I get this error

Run-time error '1004':

Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: If you change the SaveToDirectory, make sure you retain the trailing backslash.

Comment: Thanks for this!

Be aware: I noticed that if there is a . in the worksheet's name, the .CSV extension is not added to the file name.

Comment: This is the best answer in this thread, no doubts. Saved me plenty of time!

Comment: Great answer! If you want to save to the same directory as the spreadsheet, you can use `SaveToDirectory = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"`

Answer (score 22):

And here's my solution should work with Excel > 2000, but tested only on 2007:

```
Private Sub SaveAllSheetsAsCSV()
On Error GoTo Heaven

' each sheet reference
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
' path to output to
Dim OutputPath As String
' name of each csv
Dim OutputFile As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

' ask the user where to save
OutputPath = InputBox("Enter a directory to save to", "Save to directory", Path)

If OutputPath <> "" Then

    ' save for each sheet
    For Each Sheet In Sheets

        OutputFile = OutputPath & "\" & Sheet.Name & ".csv"

        ' make a copy to create a new book with this sheet
        ' otherwise you will always only get the first sheet
        Sheet.Copy
        ' this copy will now become active
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=OutputFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Next

End If

Finally:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

Exit Sub

Heaven:
MsgBox "Couldn't save all sheets to CSV." & vbCrLf & _
        "Source: " & Err.Source & " " & vbCrLf & _
        "Number: " & Err.Number & " " & vbCrLf & _
        "Description: " & Err.Description & " " & vbCrLf

GoTo Finally
End Sub
```

*(OT: I wonder if SO will replace some of my minor blogging)*

Comment: Thanks! Works in Office 2010. Took me a while to realise had to leave off the trailing "/" in the filepath otherwise gives errors

Answer (score 14):

Building on Graham's answer, the extra code saves the workbook back into it's original location in it's original format.

```
Public Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()

Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SaveToDirectory As String

Dim CurrentWorkbook As String
Dim CurrentFormat As Long

 CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
 CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
' Store current details for the workbook

      SaveToDirectory = "C:\"

      For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
          WS.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & WS.Name, xlCSV
      Next

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CurrentWorkbook, FileFormat:=CurrentFormat
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
' Temporarily turn alerts off to prevent the user being prompted
'  about overwriting the original file.

End Sub
```

Comment: sorry but why do you need to save the original workbook? You can just close it without changes, can't you? Then you have created all the .csv-files before as well.

Comment: You are correct, you don't have to.  It depends on your workflow.  The save is to restore the current workbook name and format.  It is then left open for the user to interact with.  If this wasn't done then when the user tries to save it, the name will be the name of the last sheet processed and the format .csv.  If you no longer require the workbook then *ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False* would work just as well

Comment: I see, this is what you intended :)

Answer (score 6):

### Use Visual Basic to loop through worksheets and save `.csv` files.

1. Open up `.xlsx` file in Excel.
2. Press <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
3. `Insert` → `Module`
4. Insert this into the module code:

   ```vb
   Public Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()

    Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim SaveToDirectory As String

    SaveToDirectory = "./"

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
       WS.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & WS.Name & ".csv", xlCSV
    Next

   End Sub
   ```
5. Run the module.

   *(i.e. Click the play button at the top and then click "Run" on the dialog, if it pops up.)*
6. Find your `.csv` files in `~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data`.

   ```sh
   open ~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data
   ```
7. Close `.xlsx` file.
8. Rinse and repeat for other `.xlsx` files.

Answer (score 4):

A small modification [to answer from Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59075/macro-to-save-each-sheet-in-an-excel-workbook-to-separate-csv-files/59078#59078) is turning on and off of auto calculation.

Surprisingly the unmodified code was working fine with VLOOKUP but failed with OFFSET. Also turning auto calculation off speeds up the save drastically.

```
Public Sub SaveAllSheetsAsCSV()
On Error GoTo Heaven

' each sheet reference
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
' path to output to
Dim OutputPath As String
' name of each csv
Dim OutputFile As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

' Save the file in current director
OutputPath = ThisWorkbook.Path


If OutputPath <> "" Then
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

' save for each sheet
For Each Sheet In Sheets

    OutputFile = OutputPath & Application.PathSeparator & Sheet.Name & ".csv"

    ' make a copy to create a new book with this sheet
    ' otherwise you will always only get the first sheet

    Sheet.Copy
    ' this copy will now become active
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=OutputFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV,     CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End If

Finally:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

Exit Sub

Heaven:
MsgBox "Couldn't save all sheets to CSV." & vbCrLf & _
        "Source: " & Err.Source & " " & vbCrLf & _
        "Number: " & Err.Number & " " & vbCrLf & _
        "Description: " & Err.Description & " " & vbCrLf

GoTo Finally
End Sub
```

Comment: _ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=OutputFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV,     CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True_ will save dates using local format

Answer (score 3):

For Mac users like me, there are several gotchas:

You cannot save to any directory you want. Only few of them can receive your saved files. More info [there](https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac034.htm)

Here is a working script that you can copy paste in your excel for Mac:

```
Public Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()

 Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim SaveToDirectory As String

 SaveToDirectory = "~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/"

 For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheet
    WS.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & WS.Name & ".csv", xlCSV
 Next

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for use on the Mac. Two things:  
  
1.  The for loop line is missing an `s` -- should be `...ThisWorkbook.Worksheet*s*` 
2.  I receive an `'[sheetname].csv' cannot be accessed`  error. Strangely, however, if I set the path to `SaveToDirectory = './'`, all sheets are successfully exported to the `~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Please look into [Von Pookie's answer](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/265154-saving-multiple-sheets-separate-csv-files-visual-basic-applications.html), all credits to him/her.

```
 Sub asdf()
Dim ws As Worksheet, newWb As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In Sheets(Array("EID Upload", "Wages with Locals Upload", "Wages without Local Upload"))
   ws.Copy
   Set newWb = ActiveWorkbook
   With newWb
      .SaveAs ws.Name, xlCSV
      .Close (False)
   End With
Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

necro post to improve this thread which I found when trying to solve this problem

This saves the csv in the same folder that the original workbook is in with the filename [workbook]_[worksheet].csv

```
Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCSV()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim savePath As String
    Dim fileName As String
    
    savePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    fileName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.SaveAs fileName:=savePath & fileName & "_" & ws.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Next ws
End Sub
```