# macro to save each worksheet into separate xls files with visual file chooser

Tags: vba, excel

I have been using the solution linked below with much success for saving multiple worksheets to separate CSVs and would like a similar solution for saving to XLS. I would like to separate each worksheet into their own XLS file but still have a file chooser to choose the path they are saved to.

I've tried to modify this code to no avail - any ideas?

[Save each sheet in a workbook to separate CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59075/macro-to-save-each-sheet-in-an-excel-workbook-to-separate-csv-files)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This solution is a hybrid of the top two from the link you provided.

```
' ---------------------- Directory Choosing Helper Functions -----------------------
' Excel and VBA do not provide any convenient directory chooser or file chooser
' dialogs, but these functions will provide a reference to a system DLL
' with the necessary capabilities
Private Type BROWSEINFO ' used by the function GetFolderName
    hOwner As Long
    pidlRoot As Long
    pszDisplayName As String
    lpszTitle As String
    ulFlags As Long
    lpfn As Long
    lParam As Long
    iImage As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" _
    Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" (ByVal pidl As Long, ByVal pszPath As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32.dll" _
    Alias "SHBrowseForFolderA" (lpBrowseInfo As BROWSEINFO) As Long

Function GetFolderName(Msg As String) As String
' returns the name of the folder selected by the user
Dim bInfo As BROWSEINFO, path As String, r As Long
Dim X As Long, pos As Integer
    bInfo.pidlRoot = 0& ' Root folder = Desktop
    If IsMissing(Msg) Then
        bInfo.lpszTitle = "Select a folder."
        ' the dialog title
    Else
        bInfo.lpszTitle = Msg ' the dialog title
    End If
    bInfo.ulFlags = &H1 ' Type of directory to return
    X = SHBrowseForFolder(bInfo) ' display the dialog
    ' Parse the result
    path = Space$(512)
    r = SHGetPathFromIDList(ByVal X, ByVal path)
    If r Then
        pos = InStr(path, Chr$(0))
        GetFolderName = Left(path, pos - 1)
    Else
        GetFolderName = ""
    End If
End Function
'---------------------- END Directory Chooser Helper Functions ----------------------

Public Sub DoTheExport()
Dim FName As Variant
Dim Sep As String
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim nFileNum As Integer
Dim xlsPath As String


xlsPath = GetFolderName("Choose the folder to export files to:")
If xlsPath = "" Then
    MsgBox ("You didn't choose an export directory. Nothing will be exported.")
    Exit Sub
End If
'MsgBox xlsPath

For Each wsSheet In Worksheets
        ' make a copy to create a new book with this sheet
        ' otherwise you will always only get the first sheet
        wsSheet.Copy
        ' this copy will now become active
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xlsPath + "\" + wsSheet.Name & ".xls", CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close

Next wsSheet

End Sub
```