# How do I save each sheet in an Excel 2010 workbook to separate CSV files with a macro?

Tags: csv, excel, zip, vba

This question is very similar to the previously posted question: [Save each sheet in a workbook to separate CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59075/1289884)

However, my requirements are slightly different in that I need to have the ability to ignore specifically named worksheets (see #2 below).

I have been successful in utilizing the solution posted in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/845345/1289884 which was posted in response to the question above meets almost all of my requirements with the exception of #2 below and #3 below:

I have an excel 2010 workbook that consists of multiple worksheets and I am looking for a macro that will:

1. Save each worksheet to a separate comma delimited CSV file.
2. Ignore specific named worksheet(s) (i.e. a sheet named TOC and sheet name Lookup)
3. Save files to a specified folder (example: c:\csv)

Ideal Solution would additionally:

1. Create a zip file consisting of all of the CSV worksheets within a specified folder

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Macro to save each sheet in an Excel workbook to separate CSV files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59075/macro-to-save-each-sheet-in-an-excel-workbook-to-separate-csv-files)

Comment: SO *has* a bonus point system, but you're not using it. Fraudster!

Comment: The solution presented in the similar response does not address my requirement.  My apologies if I should have posted to that thread.

Comment: @NickFlorez, update this question with what specifically is missing for you in the allegedly duplicate question. If it's just the *answers* to that question you're not satisfied with, then how's this question not a duplicate?

Comment: @bzlm I didn't believe the question was a duplicate due to the fact that my requirements are different.  I couldn't find a way to post a follow up question to that thread.  Is that what I should have done?

Comment: I wouldn't be using the accepted answer in that thread though - it writes cell by cell.

Comment: @brettdj Can you please propose a better solution?

Comment: There are other decent answers in that thread Nick, all you need to add is a 1) `If` text to exclude unwanted sheets 2) a save path to `c:\csv`. The zipping is a little more complex so we can help with that. If you try (1) and (2) which meets the spirit of SO then we can jump in and help :)

Comment: @brettdj I have no programming experience but certainly willing to give it a shot.  Can you recommend an answer that I should I build my proposed solution off of?

Comment: This is as good as any - plus its simple. http://stackoverflow.com/a/59906/641067

Comment: @NickFlorez, if all else fails, you may get better help at [Super User](http://superuser.com). But the real macro wizards probably hang out here as well. :)

Comment: Nick, post back if you are struggling and we will help you here. I wouldn't recommend Super User for VBA code support

Comment: @brettdj I have been successful in all steps with the exception of creating a zip file.  If that is easily done I would love the help. Otherwise, I am satisfied with the current solution. Thank you for the follow up.

Comment: Nick - well done!. In parallel I have added full working code below.

Answer (score 2):

Nick,

Given you expanded on your question with the differences, and the zip part is a significant addon I have outlined a solution below that:

1. Creates the CSV file, skipping specific sheets using this line `Case "TOC", "Lookup"`
2. Adds them to a Zip file. This section draws heavily on [Ron de Bruin's code here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/windowsxpunzip.htm)

The code will create the paths under `StrMain` and `StrZipped` if they do not already exists

As the `ActiveWorkbook` gets sub-divided into CSV files the code tests that the `ActiveWorkbook` is saved prior to proceeding

On (2) I ran across an issue I have seen before in my [Produce an Excel list of the attributes of all MP3 files that sit in or below the "My Music" folde](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_2839-Produce-an-Excel-list-of-the-attributes-of-all-MP3-files-that-sit-in-or-below-the-My-Music-folder.html) where the `Shell.Application` errored when string variables were passed to it. So I gritted my teeth and added a hardcoding of the earlier paths for `Zip_All_Files_in_Folder`. I commented out my earlier variable passing to show where I tried this

**`VBA to save CSVS`**

```
    Public Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strMain As String
    Dim strZipped As String
    Dim strZipFile As String
    Dim lngCalc As Long

    strMain = "C:\csv\"
    strZipped = "C:\zipcsv\"
    strZipFile = "MyZip.zip"

    If Not ActiveWorkbook.Saved Then
    MsgBox "Pls save " & vbNewLine & ActiveWorkbook.Name & vbNewLine & "before running this code"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        lngCalc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    'make output diretcories if they don't exist
    If Dir(strMain, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then MkDir strMain
    If Dir(strZipped, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then MkDir strZipped

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case ws.Name
        Case "TOC", "Lookup"
            'do nothing for these sheets
        Case Else
            ws.SaveAs strMain & ws.Name, xlCSV
        End Select
    Next

    'section to run the zipping
    Call NewZip(strZipped & strZipFile)
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Call Zip_All_Files_in_Folder '(strZipped & strZipFile, strMain)
    'end of zipping section

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = lngCalc
    End With

    End Sub
```

'**`Create the ZIP file if it doesn't exist`**

```
    Sub NewZip(sPath As String)
    'Create empty Zip File
    'Changed by keepITcool Dec-12-2005
    If Len(Dir(sPath)) > 0 Then Kill sPath
    Open sPath For Output As #1
    Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
    Close #1
    End Sub
```

'**`Add the files to the Zip file`**

```
    Sub Zip_All_Files_in_Folder() '(sPath As String, ByVal strMain)

    Dim oApp As Object
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    'Shell doesn't handle the variable strings in my testing. So hardcode the same paths :(
    sPath = "C:\zipcsv\MyZip.zip"
    strMain = "c:\csv\"

    'Copy the files to the compressed folder
    oApp.Namespace(sPath).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(strMain).items
    MsgBox "You find the zipfile here: " & sPath
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I sincerely appreciate this.  Great work.

Comment: Any way to save the file in its original format in its original location once the macro runs?

Comment: @NickFlorez add an `ActiveWorkbook.Save` at the start of the code.