# Automatically convert an xlsx file into multiple (MS-DOS) CSV files (one per sheet) in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, excel, csv, xlsx

Currently I'm just saving the file as MS-DOS CSV with excel. I'm looking for the fastest way (in terms of writing the code) of doing it automatically.

I strongly prefer C++, but any simple executable program I can call from a C++ app would do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/59075/560648

Answer (score 0):

Unzip the `xslx` file with eg WinZip and have a look at the resulting files. This may help.