# How can i split an Excel (.xls) file that contains multiple sheets into separate excel files?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel `.xls` file that contains 10 sheets. I want to split all of those sheets as separate `.xls` files. Does excel have any option to export a sheet into a separate `.xls` file?

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59075

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Splitbook()

    Dim xPath As String
    xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    xWs.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xls", fileformat:=56 
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

These are the main file formats in Excel 2007-2013, Note: In Excel for the Mac the values are +1

```
51 = xlOpenXMLWorkbook (without macro's in 2007-2013, xlsx)
52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled (with or without macro's in 2007-2013, xlsm)
50 = xlExcel12 (Excel Binary Workbook in 2007-2013 with or without macro's, xlsb)
56 = xlExcel8 (97-2003 format in Excel 2007-2013, xls)
6 = ".csv"
-4158 = ".txt"
36 = ".prn"
```

All file formats codes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx)

Comment: its working .. but while trying to open file its showing one  message"that file trying to open different format that specified file extension.verify that  file not corrupted and is form a trusted source  before opening file "

Comment: is it possible to convert csv file ?

Comment: acept the answer if solved